# I have to create google maps for android but the code I presently have is in java script developed in .net

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jsp

My maps project is basically developed by using java script in **.net**,
All the files are in .cs format. I want to convert this entire project into android project
or if there is any source code present please provide me.

I am presently using android development tool plugin for android development.
The default sample maps is not working in my eclipse.
Suggest me any other options?
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: use google maps api 2 for android. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: The min api i have is 3

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with using c# already and really only need the maps. You should look into [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/android)

Comment: I recently downloaded XamarinInstaller.exe in my desktop. If i double click that is shows a check box stating that"Automatically send the trouble shoot information and usage statistics to help improve improve this software", When i click continue,it disappears and no response at all.I checked the task manager it shows nothing.Finally i tried to run as administrator it sill didn't work.I am presently using windowsXp 32 bit.please give me a solution.

Comment: your issue is you are running XP.